# Incompatible version (AGP 8.3.0) of the Android Gradle plugin

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I am currently on  **Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 1** and I get this issue trying to compile the general project I am working on with this error

*The project is using an incompatible version (AGP 8.3.0) of the Android Gradle plugin. Latest supported version is AGP 8.2.1*

I don't want to downgrade the gradle in the project to 3.2.1. how can I resolve this

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to downgrade AGP, you have to upgrade Android Studio. *Iguana* is the first compatible version.

Comment: My fear is upgrading android studio might affect other project... do you know other alternative.. can I install the specific gradle version to satisfy this error or if i need to install a specific version

Comment: Newer versions of Android Studio should be able to work with older projects. It's just that the newer AGP version only works with newer AS versions. I don't think there is a viable alternative than to choose a compatible pair of AGP and AS.

Comment: I found my self upgrading my android studio and it does installed the require dependency.. now fixed